# Custom Exception not thrown in controller-method when no data is found in database

Tags: spring-boot

My controller always give **Internal server error** whenever my condition fail, and are suppose to throw custom exception `ResourceNotFoundException`.
When I call `account/1`-endpoint (no account with id 1 in database) I expect an `ResourceNotFoundException`, but instead I get **Internal server Error**.. I do not understand why `ResourceNotFoundException` is not thrown, I watched several youtube tutorials on the topic.
Please help by providing possible solutions.

My model classes are

```java
    package com.bank2.Model;
    
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    
    
    @Entity
    @javax.persistence.Table(name="Account")
    @Proxy(lazy = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Account {
    
        
        
        @Id
        int accountNumber;
        @Column(name="balance")
        Double balance;
        @Column(name="accountType")
        String accountType;
        
    public Account() {
            super();
       }
     
    
        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [accountNumber=" + accountNumber + ", balance=" + balance + ", accountType=" + accountType + "]";
    }
    
        public int getAccountNumber() {
            return accountNumber;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }
    
    
    
        public Double getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setBalance(Double balance) {
            this.balance = balance;
        }
    
    
    
        public String getAccountType() {
            return accountType;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
            this.accountType = accountType;
        }
    
    
    
    
        public Account(int accountNumber, Double balance, String accountType) {
            super();
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.accountType = accountType;
        }
    
        
    }
```

```java
    package com.bank2.Model;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Customer")
    @Proxy(lazy = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Customer {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        Integer customerId;
        @Column(name="customerName")
        String customerName;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = Account.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ca_fk",referencedColumnName ="customerId")
        private List<Account> accounts;
    
        public Customer() {
            super();
        }
    
        public Customer(Integer customerId, String customerName, List<Account> accounts) {
            super();
            this.customerId = customerId;
            this.customerName = customerName;
            this.accounts = accounts;
        }
    
        public Integer getCustomerId() {
            return customerId;
        }
    
        public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
            this.customerId = customerId;
        }
    
        public String getCustomerName() {
            return customerName;
        }
    
        public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
            this.customerName = customerName;
        }
    
        public List<Account> getAccount() {
            return accounts;
        }
    
        public void setAccount(List<Account> accounts) {
            this.accounts = accounts;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Customer [customerId=" + customerId + ", customerName=" + customerName + ", accounts=" + accounts + "]";
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
```

My service classes are

```java
    package com.bank2.ServiceImpl;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import com.bank2.Model.Customer;
    import com.bank2.repository.CustomerRepository;
    
    @Service
    public class CustomerService  {
    
        @Autowired
        CustomerRepository customerRepository;
        
        public Customer customerCreate(Customer customer) {
           Customer x= customerRepository.save(customer);
           return x;
        }
    
    }
```

```java
    package com.bank2.ServiceImpl;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import com.bank2.Model.Account;
    import com.bank2.repository.AccountRepository;
    
    @Service
    public class AccountService {
        
        @Autowired
        AccountRepository accountRepository;
    
        public Account findAccountById(int accountNumber) {
                
                return  accountRepository.getById(accountNumber);
            }
    
        
        
        
    }
```

my controller class are

```java
    package com.bank2.controller;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import com.bank2.Exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
    import com.bank2.Model.Account;
    import com.bank2.ServiceImpl.AccountService;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/account")
    public class AccountController {
    
        @Autowired
        AccountService accountService;
        
        @GetMapping("/{accountNumber}")
            public ResponseEntity<?> getAccountById(@PathVariable("accountNumber") int accountNumber){
                Account acc=accountService.findAccountById(accountNumber);
                if(acc==null) {
                    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Account [accountNumber="+accountNumber+"] can't be found");
                }else {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(acc,HttpStatus.FOUND);
                }
                
    
        }
```

```java
    package com.bank2.controller;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import com.bank2.Exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
    import com.bank2.Model.Customer;
    import com.bank2.ServiceImpl.CustomerService;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/customer")
    public class CustomerController {
    
        @Autowired
        CustomerService customerService;
        
        @PostMapping("/createCust")
            public ResponseEntity<?> CreateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
            Customer cus=customerService.customerCreate(customer);
            Optional<Customer> cus1 = Optional.ofNullable(cus);
            if(cus1.isEmpty()) {
                          throw new ResourceNotFoundException("customer not created!!");
                }else {
                     return new ResponseEntity<>(cus,HttpStatus.CREATED);
                   }
             }
    
    }
```

my expection classes are

```java
    package com.bank2.Exception;
    
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    
    
    
    
    public class ApiErrors {
    
        String message;
        List<String> details;
        HttpStatus status;
        LocalDateTime timestamp;
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        public List<String> getDetails() {
            return details;
        }
        public void setDetails(List<String> details) {
            this.details = details;
        }
        public HttpStatus getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }
        public void setTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
        public ApiErrors() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public ApiErrors(String message, List<String> details, HttpStatus status, LocalDateTime timestamp) {
            super();
            this.message = message;
            this.details = details;
            this.status = status;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ApiErrors [message=" + message + ", details=" + details + ", status=" + status + ", timestamp="
                    + timestamp + "]";
        }
            
        
    }
```

```java
    package com.bank2.Exception;
    
    public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        public ResourceNotFoundException() {
            super();
        }
    
        public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
        
        
        
        
        
    
    }
```

```java
    package com.bank2.Exception;
    
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
    import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
    import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
    import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
    
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
        
        
        @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex){
            
            String msg=ex.getMessage();
            List<String> details=new ArrayList<>();
            details.add("Resource not found");
            ApiErrors errors=new ApiErrors(msg,details,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,LocalDateTime.now());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errors,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleOther(Exception ex){
            
            String msg=ex.getMessage();
            List<String> details=new ArrayList<>();
            details.add("Other Exceptions");
            ApiErrors errors=new ApiErrors(msg,details,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,LocalDateTime.now());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errors,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

This is the **Internal server error** I have gotten so far in Postman:

```java
    {
        "message": "Unable to find com.bank2.Model.Account with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.bank2.Model.Account with id 1",
        "details": [
            "Other Exceptions"
        ],
        "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "timestamp": "2022-04-02T22:09:28.0486246"
    }
```

My repositories are

```
'''
package com.bank2.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.bank2.Model.Account;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {
    
}

'''
'''
package com.bank2.repository;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.bank2.Model.Customer;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
  
    
    
}

'''
```

Comment: How does your `AccountRepository.java ` look like?

Comment: I will post here

Comment: please provide me a solution

Comment: Please remove code from comments and just add to your problem. Remember to format using three backticks (```) instead of '''. Also, if you have the application logs, please provide them as well.

Comment: I have already posted see my question you will find all...please help me

Comment: ```package com.bank2.repository; import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository; import com.bank2.Model.Account; @Repository public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> { }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Documentation [JpaRepository.html#getById-ID-](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getById-ID-)

> **T getById(ID id)**
>
> Returns a reference to the entity with the
> given identifier. Depending on how the JPA persistence provider is
> implemented this is very likely to always return an instance and ***throw
> an EntityNotFoundException*** on first access. Some of them will reject
> invalid identifiers immediately.

The error message you get shows `...nested exception is EntityNotFoundException`, so that could be normal...

So you could throw a `ResourceNotFoundException` in your service when the Account is not found.

```java
 @Service
 public class AccountService {

   public Account findAccountById(int accountNumber) {
      try {
       return  accountRepository.getById(accountNumber);
      } catch(EntityNotFoundException e) {
          throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Account [accountNumber="+accountNumber+"] can't be found")
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Giri, you should try this, and check if you get `ResourceNotFoundException` in response. And if not, what type of exception do you get?